# Angular, Jasmine: Mock constant imported from external file

Tags: angular, jasmine

Let's say there is a constant exported from file. Then there is a method in component, which uses this constant. And finally, there is a test spec which tests this method.

How to simulate this constant to make the test working?

```
// constants.ts
export const myConst = 20;

// component.ts
import { myConst } from './constants.ts'

isEqualToConstValue(testedValue: number) {
  return testedValue == myConst;
}

// component.spec.ts
describe('isEqualToConstValue', () => {
  it ('should return true for 20', () => {
    const result = component.isEqualToConstValue(20); // <= this is evaluated to 'false' since myConst is not known inside the method

    expect(result).toBeTrue();
  })
})
```

Comment: Your code seems correct AND Inside your component, `myConst` is known. Your problem should be somewhere else

Comment: How do you initiate `component` in your test?

Comment: I would expect this to work without doing something specific..? The component instance you create in your test should have that import.. but I might be missing something..?